# How to print the fibonacci sequence in reverse order WITHOUT using a loop

Tags: java, algorithm

I got this question in an interview. It's easy until the part when the interviewer wants me to not use the loop I used in the print method. number of terms is an input, when it's 7, For example: print 13 8 5 3 2 1 1. He said it's easy in Python but I can write the mechanism in Java too but I can't think of which mechanism he may be referring to. Thank you!

My Java code:

```
public class Fibonacci {
    private int[] a;

    private int fib(int i) {
        assert (i>=0);

        if (a[i]==0) {
            if (i==0 || i==1) {
                a[i] = 1;
            } else {
                a[i] = fib(i - 2) + fib(i - 1);
            }
        }

        return a[i];
    }

    public Fibonacci(int numberTerms) {
        if (numberTerms<2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("expect at least 2 terms for a Fibonacci sequence");
        a = new int[numberTerms];
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i=a.length; i!=0; i--) {
            System.out.println(fib(i-1));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fibonacci f = new Fibonacci(7);
        f.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe recursion?  But I can't think why you would want to do that, recursion is a poor choice for Fibonacci.  Sounds like a poor interviewer.

Comment: Thanks guys. My fib method is a recursive method. I don't need the for loop if I'm asked to print the sequence forward, it's just hard to see how to satisfy both "print backward" and "don't use a loop" at the same time...

Comment: There is actually a closed form of the Fibonacci sequence - no loop or recursion required at all...

Comment: Boris, although the interviewer was more interesting in seeing how I understand recursion, there is a closed form formula, you are absolutely right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, you could have made a recursive `print`; that is this -

```
public void print() {
  for (int i=a.length; i!=0; i--) {
    System.out.println(fib(i-1));
  }
}
```

Could have been something like,

```
public void print() {
  print(a.length - 1);
}
```

and

```
public void print(int i) {
  if (i > 0) {
    System.out.println(fib(i - 1));
    print(i - 1);
  }
}
```

When I run the above, I get the requested output of

```
13
8
5
3
2
1
1
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public static int f(int n){
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    else 
        return f(n-1) + f(n-2);
}

static void printReversedFib(int x){
    if(x <= 1)
        System.out.println(f(x));
    else{
        System.out.println(f(x));
        printReverseFib(x-1);
    }
}
```

Testing with `printReversedFib(7);` will print:

```
13
8
5
3
2
1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the reverse way like that. Who could enhance it? All suggestions are welcome.

```
    package com.jbjares.dynamicProgramming;

    public class Fibonacci {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Fibonacci().calc(317811,1);
    }

    public void calc(Integer start,Integer end){
                    Integer f = (int) (start/((1+Math.sqrt(5))/2));
                    System.out.println(f);
                    if(f==end){
                            return;
                    }
                    calc(++f,end);
    }

}
```

Result:
196417
121393
75025
46368
28657
17711
10946
6765
4181
2584
1597
987
610
377
233
144
89
55
34
21
13
8
5
3
2
1

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this easily using DP (Dynamic Prog.)
All you need to do is create the DP array and then you can iterate the array in reverse order.
Below is the solution in Go.
http://play.golang.org/p/3m1n_AUSZl

```
func FibPrintRev(n int) {
    space := make([]int, n+1)
    // base case
    space[1] = 1
    space[2] = 1

    // Create dp array
    for i := 3; i <= n; i++ {
      space[i] = space[i-1] + space[i-2]
    }
    // Iterate in rev. order
    for i := n; i > 0; i-- {
      fmt.Println(space[i])
    }
}
```